# SELECT records from two table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables :

PEOPLE

```
ID        |NAME       
|A2112    |John       
|B3200    |Mary       
|C2454    |Bob        
|F2256    |Joe
```

JOBS

```
|ID        |NAME          |PEOPLE 
|56565     |Taxi Driver   |A2112
|23232     |Herborist     |A2112  
|12125     |Jumper        |B3200  
|25425     |Taxi Driver   |C2454  
|12456     |Taxi Driver   |F2256  
|56988     |Herborist     |F2256  
|45459     |Superhero     |F2256
```

I wonder how I can select any records FROM People that have JOBS ID 56565 AND 23232 in performant way.

The search pattern may be two or multiples jobs, and the records can have another jobs too.

So the result will be John and Joe in this example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite sure if I got you right. This will return people who have job 56565 and/or 23232:

```
select distinct p.name
from people p
  join jobs j on p.id = j.peopleid
where j.id in (56565, 23232)
```

If BOTH jobs are required:

```
select p.name
from people p
  join jobs j on p.id = j.peopleid
where j.id in (56565, 23232)
group by p.name
having count(*) > 1
```

The `HAVING` clause can also be written as

```
having max(j.id) <> min(j.id)
```

Perhaps better performance that way.

Comment: Thank you Jarlh this is exactly what i am asked for.

Answer (score 4):

The [INNER JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables.

```
SELECT
    p.NAME, COUNT(*) as tot
FROM
    PEOPLE p 
        INNER JOIN JOBS j ON (p.ID = j.PEOPLE)
WHERE
    j.ID IN (56565, 23232)
GROUP BY
    p.NAME
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

[Visual explanation](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) of INNER JOIN bellow:

[image: Visual explanation of INNER JOIN]

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM PEOPLE as p
    JOIN JOB as j ON j.PEOPLE = p.ID
    WHERE j.ID IN(56565, 23232)
```

Answer (score 0):

"People *that have* JOBS" translates to `WHERE EXISTS` in SQL:

```
select *
from people
where exists
(
  select *
  from jobs
  where jobs.people = people.id
  and jobs.id in (56565, 23232)
);
```

This can also be written with an `IN` clause, which I even consider slightly more readable for its simplicity:

```
select *
from people
where id in
(
  select people
  from jobs
  where id in (56565, 23232)
);
```